Calculating total score of a column
I have a google sheets with the following format:
A list of rows that list criteria
A list of cols per row that either have a numerical value from 1-10 or a yes/no answer (I guess could be represented as 1/0).
Question:
How can I assign weights per row so that at the bottom of each column I get a total summed score which would be the sum of weight * col_value over a column?

Your question is confusing. Please [edit] it to include a couple of examples using some example data, and desired result.


If your weighting is in column A;
Your values are in B2:G100
Your formula could be
=BYCOL(B2:G100, LAMBDA(col, 
   SUMPRODUCT(A2:A100, col)))


If your weighting is relative, your formula could be:
=BYCOL(B2:G100, LAMBDA(col, 
   SUMPRODUCT(A2:A100, A2:A100/SUM(A2:A100)))



